# Select2 - Add attributes to option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

**My code**

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MauroBros/68p70sy1/)

**Output**

```
<option value="ga:impressions" data-select2-id="select2-data-3-n2fi">Impressions</option>
//...
```

**I need to add this:**

> type="dimension" filterobj="{"isFilter":true}

**to each option tag in order to get this output**

```
<option value="ga:impressions" type="dimension" filterobj="{&quot;isFilter&quot;:true} data-select2-id="select2-data-3-n2fi"">Impressions</option>
// ...
```

So I tried to edit the variable element in my code in this way, but didn't work

```
var element = $(this).children("option[value="+id+" type="dimension" filterobj="{&quot;isFilter&quot;:true}"]")
```

Any help?

Comment: Please post all relevant code without outside links so we can better help you

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting around the quotes in the string you concatenate in the `children()` selector. You need to either escape the `"` or use `'` the delimit the string and `"` to delimit the attributes. I'd suggest the latter as it's easier to read. Also note that you shouldn't append non-standard attributes to your elements (ie. `type="dimension"` and `filterobj`. Use `data` attributes to add metadata to the element and to keep your HTML valid.

Comment: It's not very clear from your question what your trying to do. Do you want to add the type attribute with js?